# Cannot access symlinked file on Apache server (403 Forbidden)

Tags: permissions, apache-http-server, symbolic-link

I'm running a minecraft server on my laptop, and I have created a symbolic link of */home/myuser/Documents/MinecraftSV/logs/latest.log* to */var/www/html*, but when I try to access it I receive a 403 Forbidden error.

I do not have a httpd.conf file on */etc/apache2*.

I've changed */etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf* to the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
<Directory />
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride Indexes
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

I've also given execute permission to the folder where the file is located all the way to the home directory and I've restarted apache service after doing all this changes.

I'm running Debian 8. Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

**Edit:** Ok, I created a new symlink (of the same file) on /html/logs and changed that folder permission to 777. I can now access this folder and its contents.

Weird, since the file I'm symlinking already has 777 permission...